# show multiple popup in same marker if it has multiple records

Tags: angular, typescript

I am developing an application to show member details on the map. so now according to the `latitude` and `longitude` showing markers on the map.

Now I want to show the popup when I click on the marker.

**this is the sample JSON data.**

```
        {
            "latitude": 55.361113939022324,
            "longitude": 10.341862268593902,
            "mapIndividualDetails": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "displayName": "Harward ",
                    "gender": "M",
                    "birthDate": "12/10/1945",
                    "aliveStatus": 1,
                    "profileImageUrl": ""
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "latitude": 58.80245685662347,
            "longitude": 5.548005344823589,
            "mapIndividualDetails": [
                {
                    "id": 7,
                    "displayName": "Serphia",
                    "gender": "F",
                    "birthDate": "19-05-1969",
                    "aliveStatus": 0,
                    "profileImageUrl": ""
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "latitude": 59.911262766392454,
            "longitude": 10.748432268893623,
            "mapIndividualDetails": [
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "displayName": "Marian",
                    "gender": "F",
                    "birthDate": "20-november-1948",
                    "aliveStatus": 2,
                    "profileImageUrl": ""
                },
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "displayName": "Emira",
                    "gender": "F",
                    "birthDate": "2022",
                    "aliveStatus": 0,
                    "profileImageUrl": ""
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "latitude": 6.837329174493352,
            "longitude": 79.8844666457689,
            "mapIndividualDetails": [
                {
                    "id": 9,
                    "displayName": "Serina Marchel ",
                    "gender": "F",
                    "birthDate": "9-mars-2023",
                    "aliveStatus": 1,
                    "profileImageUrl": ""
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "latitude": 61.756876374952625,
            "longitude": 24.295641657032693,
            "mapIndividualDetails": [
                {
                    "id": 6,
                    "displayName": "Jonethan Agado ",
                    "gender": "M",
                    "birthDate": "21-11-1997",
                    "aliveStatus": 2,
                    "profileImageUrl": ""
                },
                {
                    "id": 11,
                    "displayName": "Selina Harward ",
                    "gender": "F",
                    "birthDate": "1990",
                    "aliveStatus": 0,
                    "profileImageUrl": ""
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "latitude": 7.469789812,
            "longitude": 80.304966588,
            "mapIndividualDetails": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "displayName": "Elon Harward ",
                    "gender": "M",
                    "birthDate": "02-05-1960",
                    "aliveStatus": 1,
                    "profileImageUrl": "http://localhost:5000/api/png/file?onlineId=NN01Id=678634de-62-89d3-5d5d4f"
                }
            ]
        }
```

here you can see some latitude and longitude has more than one record. in such a case I want to show 2 popup box in the same marker. link on top of the popup shows another popup. But with this code always show only member data which has 2 records in the same lat, long. So here how to fix this issue.

```
initMarkers(): void {
    for (const individual of this.mapIndividualsList) {
      const markers = this.theme.themeExe.getMarkers(individual);
      const popups = this.theme.themeExe.getPopUps(individual);

      for (let i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        const marker = markers[i];
        const popup = popups[i];

        marker.setLngLat([individual.longitude, individual.latitude]).addTo(this.map);

        // Attach click event listener to the marker
        marker.getElement().addEventListener('click', () => {
          // Set the popup on the marker
          marker.setPopup(popup);

          // Open the popup
          marker.togglePopup();
        });
      }
    }
}



export class StreetThemeExe extends CustomMapThemeExe {
  
  getMarkers(mapIndividuals: MapIndividualsViewModel): mapboxgl.Marker[] {
    const markers: mapboxgl.Marker[] = [];
    mapIndividuals.mapIndividualDetails.forEach((individual) => {
      let markerColor: string;

      if (individual.gender === 'M') {
        markerColor = 'blue';
      } else if (individual.gender === 'F') {
        markerColor = 'pink';
      } else {
        markerColor = 'gray';
      }

      const marker = new mapboxgl.Marker({
        color: markerColor,
      })
        .setLngLat([mapIndividuals.latitude, mapIndividuals.latitude]);

      markers.push(marker);
    });

    return markers;
  }

  getPopUps(mapIndividuals: MapIndividualsViewModel): mapboxgl.Popup[] {
    const popups: mapboxgl.Popup[] = [];
    mapIndividuals.mapIndividualDetails.forEach((individual) => {
      let popupColor: string;
  
      if (individual.gender === 'M') {
        popupColor = 'blue';
      } else if (individual.gender === 'F') {
        popupColor = 'pink';
      } else {
        popupColor = 'gray';
      }
  
      const content = `
        <div>
          <p><strong>Name:</strong> ${individual.displayName}</p>
          <p><strong>Birth Date:</strong> ${individual.birthDate}</p>
          <p><strong>Death Date:</strong> ${individual.deathDate}</p>
          ${individual.profileImageUrl ? `<img src="${individual.profileImageUrl}" alt="Profile Image">` : ''}
        </div>
      `;
  
      const popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({ closeButton: false });
  
      // Set the popup content
      popup.setHTML(content);
  
      // Set the popup background color after the content is set and the DOM is loaded
      popup.on('open', () => {
        const popupElement = popup.getElement();
        if (popupElement) {
          popupElement.style.backgroundColor = popupColor;
        }
      });
  
      popups.push(popup);
    });
    return popups;
  } 
}
```

**Model class**

```
export class MapIndividualsViewModel {
  latitude: number;
  longitude: number;
  mapIndividualDetails: MapIndividualDetails[]
}
export class MapIndividualDetails {
  id: number;
  displayName: string;
  gender: string;
  birthDate: string;
  deathDate: string;
  aliveStatus: AliveStatus;
  profileImageUrl: string;
}
```